# Simperium error: couldn't diff dates because their classes weren't NSDate

Tags: ios, core-data, simperium

This is my first time trying to integrate Simperium in one of my iOS core data projects. Though the initial sync works great. I'm seeing a ton of crashes at later stages with the following log.

> 2013-03-26 18:40:08.460 APP[2468:ae03] ********* Assertion failure in -[SPMemberDate diff:otherValue:], /path/to/simperium-ios-develop/Simperium/SPMemberDate.m:48
>
> 2013-03-26 18:40:08.465 APP[2468:ae03] ********* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Simperium error: couldn't diff dates because their classes weren't NSDate'

Printing the results of `[thisValue class]` & `[otherValue class]` in the method that occupies line 48 of SPMemberDate.m shows that at one point, thisValue is an `__NSDate` object, while otherValue is `__NSCFNumber` object.

The values of the culprit objects are always the following :-

`1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000` for `thisValue`

and

`0` for `otherValue`

I'm at loss for where to look next to try & debug this issue. What could be returning an NSNumber instead of an NSDate? And, what could be returning a date from the 70s? I'm fairly ceratin, it's nothing in my code. Any help would be nice.

Comment: That may be time interval sice 1970... you need to convert that into a date.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya That is already returned as an NSDate. Where & how exactly should I be converting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you only syncing between iOS devices, or are you also syncing to a web app or backend service? Date values are currently transmitted as numbers on the wire (number of seconds since 1970), so if you're sending dates to Simperium from a non-iOS device, you'll need to use that format.

The Simperium iOS library should be handling conversion to/from NSDate on iOS though. It's open source, so you can try downloading it and digging in a bit further to see what might be going wrong:
https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios

Comment: Thanks Mike! Already did that. I found that, one of the date attributes in the entity I'm trying to sync which is nil in most cases, is what was causing all the havoc. I took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the number as timeinterval since 1970,

You can convert it into date by:

```
// The time interval 
NSTimeInterval theTimeInterval = ...;
// Get the system calendar
NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

// Create the NSDates
NSDate *date1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:theTimeInterval sinceDate:date1];
```

Comment: The returned number is always 0, when the crash occurs. If it is indeed the time interval since 1970 as you say, I would like to find out what is returning it, before blindly making changes to a 3rd party framework, because nothing in my code should be returning a 0 timeinterval since 1970 date. I could be wrong, but I suspect this could something in the Simperium framework.

Comment: Then I dont have much idea on this :(